# Easton EC90 TKO wheels, tire options

Tags: 27-inch

Does anyone have experience with tires for these rims? I've been looking at tubulars, and many of them (especially track versions) are listed as being 27x3/4 or 27x1, as opposed to 700x19 and 700x22. Specifically, I'm looking at picking up a pair of [Continental Tempos](http://www.conti-online.com/generator/www/de/en/continental/bicycle/themes/race/tubulartrack/tempo/tempo_en.html) but am unsure if the sizing is correct. Is this simply a case of labeling inconsistency, or will the tires not fit my rims?

Comment: This is very weird. I've never heard of anybody making 27" tubular rims or tires. Do any companies besides Continental do this?

Comment: I hadn't heard of these either, but [google says they exist](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&nord=1&site=webhp&tbm=shop&source=hp&q=27+inch+bicycle+wheels&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f6b2ace10b1fd848&biw=1280&bih=679&ion=1). These were, from what I can find, [popular through the 1980s](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/harris/wheels/630.html).

Comment: Neil, 27" tubulars are different from 27" clinchers. But yes, both exist, and neither are compatible with the 700c versions. 630mm BSD vs 622mm BSD (as the Sheldon page tells you).

Comment: The part that confuses me is that I can find Continental Tempos for sale that are 700x19 and 700x22, but Continental's webpage only states the 27x3/4 and 27x1 measurements. It makes me suspect they're the actually the same tires.

Comment: They aren't. Look for Schwalbe tires. They are high quality readily available tubulars in 700c sizes, and a variety of prices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, I purchased the tires. It's simply a case of inconsistent labeling. The 27x1 tires are effectively 700x22.

Comment: Arrrgh! That's great for you, and no doubt is part of the secret tubular lore that us great unwashed don't know (and get tripped by if we get involved).

Comment: They are actually, according to continental, not the same size. hey are similar, and may not appear different, but they may not stay on the wheel properly, since the internal diameter is not the same as a 700. Unless they were mislabeled as 27" on the website, but say 700c on the tire?

Comment: They say 27"x22 on the tire itself.